# Pre-populate FK relation with logged in user without dropdown in GET request

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I would like to pre-populate fields with driver info into html page(more driver into needed) which he already filled during registration(as a normal user)
for example "username"

I am able to do for all fields except user field is shown as dropdown with all the users list in html page

[image]

Here are my urls, models, forms, views and html page info:

urls.py

```
path('driver_info/', driver_info, name='driver_info'),
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def driver_info(request):
    p_form = DriverUserInfoForm(instance=request.user.driverprofile)
    context = {
        'p_form' : p_form
    }    
    return render(request, 'driver/driver_info.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class DriverProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    driving_license_number = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True, verbose_name="DL Number")
    expiry_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="DL Expiry Date")
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class DriverUserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = DriverProfile
        exclude = ('is_verified', 'is_active',)
```

drive_info.html

```
{% block content %} 

<h3>Driver info</h3>

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ p_form }}

    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

In- case CustomUser model needed, here it is:

users/models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I have tried to set the value in **init** method inside forms.py but no luck
I tried having a new CharField in forms.py but not able to fill the value with current user username

**Could someone please help me how do I have only current user instead of all the users? **

Answer (score 1):

first, exclude the user from the form

```
class DriverUserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = DriverProfile
        exclude = ('is_verified', 'is_active', 'user',)
```

now you need to set logged in user as user field

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def driver_info(request):
    p_form = DriverUserInfoForm(instance=request.user.driverprofile)
    if p_form.is_valid:
       new_form = p_form.save(commit=False)
       new_form.user = request.user
       new_form.save()
    context = {
        'p_form' : p_form
    }    
    return render(request, 'driver/driver_info.html', context)
```

now user automatically set.

about showing the logged in user name, I have not to much experiance with html for show name in the form field, but you can easily show user name using

```
{{ user.username }}
```

in your template